# Supabase .net C#: Is it possible to refresh the token or SignOut on a web API?

Tags: c#, .net, jwt, supabase

I am currently working on an API using Supabase. I am using .net6 (C#) and injecting the Supabase Client **as Scoped**.
I would like to know if it is possible to refresh a token for a user with the client.
I also would like to know if it is possible to Signout a user via its token.

```
  
    [HttpPost("refresh")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> RefreshAsync(string token)
    {
        var user = await _supabase.Auth.GetUser(token);
        await _supabase.Auth.RefreshSession();
        
        return Ok();
    }
```

As you can see I could retrieve the user via its token, but I am not able to refresh its Session.

```
  [HttpPost("logout")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> LogoutAsync(string token)
    {
        try
        {
            var user = await _supabase.Auth.GetUser(token);
            await _supabase.Auth.SignOut();
            
            return Ok();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
            throw;
        }
    }
```

It is the same with the SignOut() method, I can't pass the user as parameter.

Do you have any idea ?

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is a public [RefreshAccessToken method](https://github.com/supabase-community/gotrue-csharp/blob/master/Gotrue/Api.cs#L598) as well as a [Signout method](https://github.com/supabase-community/gotrue-csharp/blob/master/Gotrue/Api.cs#L451)

Can you try these, and if you're facing issues with them, I'd recommend opening an issue directly on the relevant repo: https://github.com/supabase-community/gotrue-csharp/issues